# Filter event logs using Get-WmiObject

Tags: powershell, logging, windows-server-2008-r2

Hi I making a powershell script in which I need to filter logs

```
$logFile = Get-WmiObject Win32_NTEventlogFile | Where-Object {$_.logfilename -eq 'Application'}
```

In the Where-Object clause I need to filter using the eventID , source(provider),start time and end time.

I don't seem to figure out how put these parameters in . Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You better use Get-WinEvent or Get-EventLog Cmdlets for this tasks:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Application | 
Where-Object {$_.Id -eq 903 -and $_.ProviderName -match "office" `
-and $_.TimeCreated -gt ((Get-Date).AddHours(-6))}
```

Of course you can use smarter and faster filters like:

`-FilterXPath`, `-FilterXml` and `-FilterHashtable` Parameters.

for more information: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849682.aspx

To Export the event file you can use the wevtutil:

```
wevtutil epl System c:\temp\system.evtx
```

for more information: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732848.aspx

To Load it from file:

```
Get-WinEvent -Path c:\temp\system.evtx
```

Comment: Thanks Avshalom.The problem is that I want a .evtx log file. And it is not possible with Get-WinEvent . Is it?

Is it possible to get system,security and application logs in one .evtx file with Get-EventLog?I know we can get separate files,but not one.

Comment: You define a query using `Get-EventLog` then export that using one of the Export cmdlets.  For example, `Export-CSV`

Comment: Guys, need to export the logs to an .evtx file specifically .
I know I can get csv or read from a file . But I need to export to an evtx file . Please help.